# For each node v: find the cheaper colorful path from s to v

Tags: algorithm

Let G = (V,E) where each node has one of three colors {R, G, B}. 

 A path (not necessarily simple) will be called colorful if it contains all the colors. 
**Input**: directed Graph G as above (including the color of each node), s∈V, and positive weights w: E → Q.
**Output**: For each node v : find the cheaper colorful path (not necessarily simple) from s to v (if none exists then return infinity).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a modified form of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), starting from the node `s`. For each path found, keep track of which colours have been used in that path so far; when inserting a continuation of the path into the priority queue, the new path may include one additional colour. When updating the "best" path at a node, there may be multiple "best" paths since two paths might use different colours, or one path might be shorter but use fewer colours.

This looks like it is a [homework problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), so I'll leave the rest of the details for you to work out for yourself.

Comment: no it's a question from previous exam . I know I should clone the graph for 8 graphs but I don't know how. after clone I'll daijkstra @kaya3